# CSS parser using PHP

Tags: php, css, parsing

Here's my css link for images:

```
background-image:url(images/background.gif);
```

I just want to add some: `../` to change the directory. So my code will look like this:

```
background-image:url(../images/background.gif);
```

How will I do that? I don't need a whole CSS parser just the code to add the `../` for the images...

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here. Do you want to do this programmatically? Why?

Comment: CSS paths are relative to the CSS file. If you want to do that alter your directory structure surely?

Comment: @Beliskner yes. I have to change the css directory of codes

Comment: Your editor doesn't support *Find & Replace*? Why PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$css = str_replace("url(images/", "url(../images/", $css);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_CSS/

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do a find and replace in your CSS for "(images/" and replace with "(../images/" ??

Comment: Why? This seems and odd thing to do programmatically

Comment: It makes us curious.. probably, they would like to alter the images that will be displayed based on a theme.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) is a CSS parser written in PHP under the MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

You must use regex to parse css correctly

```
regex to parse your code  :  '/(url)\s*\(\s*[\w\W]+\)/ms'
```