# Change the directory of all images in a CSS file

Tags: php, css, parsing

This question is related to one i posted [earlier:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886067/css-parser-using-php), I have here the css file containing this code:

```
body {
    background-image:url(images/background.gif);
    color: #7a7e33;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header {
    background-image:url(images/header.jpg);
    width: 707px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 240px;
    padding:0px;
}
#content{
    background-image:url(images/sheetmiddle.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    position:relative;
}
#sheettop{
    background-image:url(images/sheet.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:707px;
}
#footer{
    background-image:url(images/footer.gif);
    width:707px;
    height:86px;
    margin-left:242px;
}
```

As you can see, there are many images directories. I want to add `../` so all the images directory will look like this:

```
background-image:url(../images/sheet.gif);
```

And all the other image directory.
How can I make a php code that will automatically read the style.css then insert this: `../` ?

From the answer on my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886067/css-parser-using-php),

```
$css = str_replace("url(images/", "url(../images/", $css);
```

What am i still missing here?

This is for my school project. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: why not just open up the style.css and do a search and replace?

Comment: Do you need to know how to open up the CSS file and read it?

Comment: what do you get from `$css` - what doesn't work. The `str_replace` looks fine.

Comment: If this is what passes for a parser project these days, sigh.

Comment: I assume this is part of a larger problem i.e. changing images based on theme, just ask us for that because maybe this is not the best solution for it.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm making my school project, a theme converter that's i have to do change the directories of a certain css file. @Arvin @kjy112

Comment: Then you can just make several css files. One is the default css (default.css) and several others for each theme (themename.css, only contains image rules). Finally, include both the default css and the css for the theme on the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$css = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/css/file'); // slurp in the file
$css = str_replace(...);  // modify the data
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/css/file', $css); // spit it back out
```