# extract css classes and ID's from source with php

Tags: php, css, regex, parsing

I thought this was going to be pretty simple, but I've been struggling with it now for a while. I know there are CSS parser classes out there that can acheive what I want to do... but I don't need 95% of the functionality they have, so they're not really feasible and would just be too heavy.

All I need to be able to do is pull out any class and/or ID names used in a CSS file via regex. Here's the regex I *thought* would work, but hasn't.

```
[^a-z0-9][\w]*(?=\s)
```

When run against my sample:

```
.stuffclass {
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.newclass{
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.oldclass {
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
#blah.newclass {
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.oldclass#blah{
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.oldclass #blah {
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.oldclass .newclass {
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #fff;
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.oldclass:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background:url('blah.jpg');
}
.newclass:active {
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

It does match *most* of what I want, but it's also including the curly brackets and doesn't match the ID's. I need to match the ID's and Classes separately when conjoined. So basically `#blah.newclass` would be 2 separate matches: `#blah` AND `.newclass`.

Any ideas?

===================

## FINAL SOLUTION

I wound up using 2 regex to first strip out everything between `{` and `}`, then simply matched the selectors based on the remaining input.

Here's a full working example:

```
//Grab contents of css file
$file = file_get_contents('css/style.css');

//Strip out everything between { and }
$pattern_one = '/(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})/s';

//Match any and all selectors (and pseudos)
$pattern_two = '/[\.|#][\w]([:\w]+?)+/';

//Run the first regex pattern on the input
$stripped = preg_replace($pattern_one, '', $file);

//Variable to hold results
$selectors = array();

//Run the second regex pattern on $stripped input
$matches = preg_match_all($pattern_two, $stripped, $selectors);

//Show the results
print_r(array_unique($selectors[0]));
```

Comment: Why not use a [complete CSS parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886067/css-parser-using-php) to extract the selectors?

Comment: What's wrong with a CSS parser? Have you run any benchmarks? Don't rule out just because you think it'd be "too heavy".

Comment: lol doh! I misspelled my own name... pfft. and I don't use a complete CSS parser because, as mentioned above, they're just far too heavy and bloated for what I want to do... They include a TON of functionality that I would never use. A simple one line regex would be ideal for this if I could just get it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^a-z0-9][\w]+(?=\s)
```

I changed your * to a + match

It works fine in RegEXR - an awesome regex development tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (See bottom right of window to download the desktop version)

Comment: perfect! thanks a ton! oops, spoke too soon... it still won't match the ID's

Comment: sorry, to be more specific... it does match the ID's when they're "standalone"... but when conjoined with a class, it does not include them in the match. `#blah.newclass`

Comment: Download RegExr and you can play with the Regex until it fits ;) Hover over each part of your regex in the top bar and RegExr will give you an explanation of what it's matching. Failing that I can have a look when I get a chance, but that may not be until tomorrow.

Comment: I wound up using 2 separate regex, one to strip out {stuff} and then another to select all the remaining matches. Updated the question with final solution and accepted your answer as you did actually point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This version is based on nealio82's, but adding pseudo-selectors:
`[^a-z0-9][\w:-]+(?=\s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<!:\s)[#.][\w]*/
```

some thing like this? excludes the #FFFFFF color stuff...

Comment: although that one does work with the sample given above, if you add things like `background: url('../img.jpg');` then ".jpg" is matched also.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by OP works, though it didn't work for me with CSS classes that had hyphens. As such, I've amended the second pattern to work more effectively:

```
$pattern_two = '/[\.|#]([A-Za-z0-9_\-])*(\s?)+/';
```